# banner animation

Tags: jquery, css-animations

Please see this IBM site - http://www.ibm.com/us/en/

If you see the site banners, there is an animation built in each banner where the text and the image slide out at a different rate and gives a really nice effect.
This is not using Flash and is probably using CSS animations.

I want to achieve similar effect with my website and need some direction.  If you are familiar with some documentation or snippets around this, that would be really helpful.

If possible, I would try to achieve this using jQuery

Comment: Have you checked out the site's source code for references to specific JavaScript libraries, perhaps?

Comment: 71 question and you accepted only 27 is that possible?...

Comment: @PratikKothari What have you tried? Or did you just come straight here expecting answers?

Comment: Why is this tagged as [tag:jquery]?

Comment: @Anish, not sure if this can be accomplished using jQuery.  I am using jQuery for some other things in the site and it would be helpful. I should have included that in the question.

Comment: @Curt - Andrew, I have seen that the site uses Dojo.  here are couple of links I have seen but don't have the exact effect - http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.6.0/dojo-release-1.6.0/dojox/widget/tests/test_Rotator.html and http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.6.0/dojo-release-1.6.0/dojox/widget/tests/test_Pager.html

Comment: Just saw this - http://sequencejs.com/themes/sliding-horizontal-parallax/ This should work for me. If you have other suggestions, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: When posting questions on SO its best to attempt something yourself, and then ask for help if you get stuck. Then users can help with particular code snippets. At the moment what answer would you be expecting? No ones going to do that for free for you. If they would then the team who did the IBM page wouldn't be making much money!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this to create the animation I needed [sequencejs.com/themes/sliding-horizontal-parallax](http://sequencejs.com/themes/sliding-horizontal-parallax)